# Print barcode as text using barcode font

Tags: zpl

I am trying to print **EAN-13** barcode without using **^BE** command. I have a barcode font 'Barcode Int 25.ttf' and I need to output my text by loading the barcode font to the printer and I don't want to use barcode(^BE) command and i can only print using zpl text commands.

I have a sample text "test" and I am trying to map this text to the font barcode.zsu that is converted using zebranetbridge tool. I download the font using DU command. Below is the sample zpl output

```
^XA
^LH0,0
^LT0
^MTD
^MNY
^MFF,F
^MMT
~TA000
^MD0
^PR2,6
^PON
^BY2,3.0,10
^CVY
^XZ
^XA
^PW2521
^LL3563
^XZ
^XA
~DUR:Barcode Int 25,15596,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 /****font stream conitnues ***/
^CWJ,R:BARCODE.FNT
^FT399,958^AJN,42^FVtest^FS
^XZ
^XA
^IDR:BARCODE.FNT^FS
^IDR:BARCODE.TTF^FS
^IDR:BARCODE.TTE^FS
^XZ
```

Am i doing something wrong here? My expectation is to print barcode dashes for the given text.

Comment: Why don't you want to use the ^BE command?

Comment: Actually we load the barcode from pdf input. In pdf the barcode is present as text with embedded font.

Comment: I'm even more confused now. Are you printing a PDF label on the Zebra? Or converting a PDF Label to ZPL?

Comment: converting pdf label to zpl..

Comment: What OS are you using to print? I know Windows has a driver that you can use to print like any printer, no need to print with ZPL.

Comment: @EdHayes3 how do i output text '123' as dashes by loading barcode font?

Comment: I have no idea what you're trying to do. Seems like your going down the wrong path though IMHO. If you're printing any barcodes, use the native ZPL functions. I've never used anything other than ZPL to the Zebra printer in production. I've mistakenly printing ZPL text as rendered Windows printing, so it literally printed the ZPL on the label. It was because I was printing with the Zebra Designer driver rather than generic text. If you really want to print a PDF label, a driver that renders and prints the bitmap, converting to ZPL like you're doing seems like hard needless work.

Comment: Hello @EdHayes3 we have framework where anything canverted to anything. for example pdf input can be converted to zpl out/pcl out and so on.. MY requirement is pretty simple I need to output text input as barcode by loading barcode font downloaded to the printer. The problem i am facing is  pdf displays text by loading barcode font. Same text is sent for zpl generation along with its associated font. I just want know if we zpl has support for this or  i have no choice except to use ^BE command to print barcode

Comment: a simple test for you would be. Open word document and write some text and select font as barcode font and you can see text gets converted to barcode. I want to achive that using zpl commands